# Optimise linq to sql query with subselect to get latest result

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm storing results from a quiz in a table, and I need to find out the latest answer ids for all questions for a particular quiz for a user (each row has id, quizid, questionid, answerid, username and datecompleted).

I've made it work, but it's so ugly I thought I'd ask for help to optimise it. I'm starting my new years resolution early, write better quality code! :) So if anyone feels like telling me how to optimise it that would be greatly appreciated!

```
public List<QuestionResult> GetLatestResult(Guid QuizID, string UserName)
    {
        List<QuestionResult> quizResult = new List<QuestionResult>();

        // first get all question ids for that quiz
        var questionIDs = (from q in db.QuizResults
                          where (q.QuizId == QuizID && q.UserName == UserName)
                          select q.QuestionId).Distinct();

        // then get the most recent answer id for those questions
        var results = from r in questionIDs
                      select (from q in db.QuizResults
                              where q.QuizId == QuizID
                              && q.UserName == UserName
                              && q.QuestionId == r
                              orderby q.DateCompleted descending
                              select q).Take(1);

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            foreach (var qr in item)
            {
                QuestionResult result = new QuestionResult();
                result.QuestionId = qr.QuestionId;
                result.AnswerId = qr.AnswerId;
                quizResult.Add(result);
            }
        }

        return quizResult;
    }
```

It's C#, linq to sql, let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks,

Annelie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var questionIDs` assignment may be removed - you already filter `QuizID` and `UserName` in a second one.

Second query may be rewritten using groups so that whole function becomes one LINQ:

```
public List<QuestionResult> GetLatestResult(Guid QuizID, string UserName) {
    return (
           from q in db.QuizResults
           where q.QuizId == QuizID && q.UserName == UserName
           group q by q.QuestionId into grouped
           select new QuestionResult {
               QuestionId = grouped.Key,
               AnswerId = grouped.OrderByDescending(q => q.CompletionDate).First().AnswerId
           };
       ).ToList();
}
```

**Edit**

Don't worry that `q` variable is used twice - after the line `group q by q.QuestionId` first `q` is out-of-scope, and this name may be used again.

Comment: Thanks, this is really nice and concise! Had to cast it for it to work, otherwise works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would attack this. The first query will give the most recent time that the user took the quiz. The second query will get the results of that quiz, selected into an IEnumerable.  The queries are only split out for readability, they could be combined with the first query being a subselect in the second.

```
public List<QuestionResult> GetLatestResult(Guid QuizID, string UserName)     
{         
    // get the latest date that this user took this quiz
    var latestQuizDate = (from q in db.QuizResults 
                          where q.QuizId == QuizID
                              && q.UserName == UserName
                          select q).Max(q => q.CompletionDate);

    // get the quiz results for this user/quiz/date 
    var results = from q in db.QuizResults
                  where q.CompletionDate = latestQuizDate
                      && q.QuizId == QuizID
                      && q.UserName == UserName
                  select new QuestionResult {q.QuestionId, q.AnswerId};

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do like splitting things up for readability, although I quite liked the grouping in Mykola's answer so picked that one this time.